# how to change the plot marker and color in the given code?

Tags: plotting

In this code, how can I have a different plot marker (say, diamond) for the plot marked by $g$? And how can I choose my favorite color for both plots $f$ and $g$?

```
{data1, data2} = 
  Transpose[
   Table[{n^2 π^3, n π Cos[1/(n^2 π^3)]}, {n, 50}]];
a = ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", ""}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"n", ""}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[FilledSquare]", 10, Blue], 
   Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", 16, Red]}]
```

[image]

**2.**

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"n", ""}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{Style["\[FilledSquare]", Blue], 10}, 
    {Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]",  Red], 16}}]
```

[image]

**3.**

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"n", ""}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]", 10}, 
    {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 16}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry, but I have another question. How can we ask to start the $n$ axis from $1$, not $0$?

Comment: @charmin, add the option `PlotRange -> {{1, All}, All}`.